# XAML Binding multiple sources

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, datacontext

Ok, I have a set of TextBlock's.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
   <TextBlock Text={Binding value1} />
   <TextBlock Text={Binding value2} />
</Grid>
```

and C# backend:

```
mydata.value1 = "value1";
mydata.value2 = "value2";
MyGrid.DataContext = mydata;
```

Now, I want to bind to this Blocks Foreground color like this:

```
//C#
private bool isViewingPage1;
private bool IsViewingPage1
{
   get { return this.isViewingPage1; }
   set
   {
      this.isViewingPage1 = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
}

//XAML
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
   <TextBlock Text={Binding value1} Foreground={Binding IsViewingPage1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}} />
   <TextBlock Text={Binding value2} Foreground={Binding IsViewingPage1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}} />
</Grid>
```

So, in case if `IsViewingPage1 == true`, the first TextBlock will be green and the second will be red. If false, the first will be red and the second - green. Converters is working good. But how I can bind two different values to one element?

I tried something like this:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MyDataType mydata;
   public bool IsViewingPage1;

   //INotifyPropertyChanged implemetation
}

//...

MyClass a = new MyClass();
a.mydata = mydata;
a.IsViewingPage1 = IsViewingPage1;
MyGrid.DataContext = a;

//XAML
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
   <TextBlock Text={Binding mydata.value1} Foreground={Binding IsViewingPage1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}} />
   <TextBlock Text={Binding mydata.value2} Foreground={Binding IsViewingPage1, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}} />
</Grid>
```

...but it did not help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The logic to determine the colour, or at least status (colour should be view specific not defined in model) of the text blocks should be in the view model. so you can have a status for each text block and bind to them, in your view model you can set the statuses of the text blocks based on the IsViewingPage bool.

Answer (score 0):

Notified properties have to be public. Change

`private bool IsViewingPage1`

to

`public bool IsViewingPage1`